Salesforce Data Cloud Data Ingestion Performance Issue: 1.5 hours to process 600+ records
We are testing Data Ingestion of Data Cloud. We noticed that the ingestion performance is quite slow. so would like to get advice here that if it is normal.
Example: we have one Data Stream which is to sync data from core CRM hourly. It is noticed that it takes around 4 to 6 minutes to process 20 to 40 records for each run (hourly) which I assume this is expected as Ingestion API runs every 3 mins.
However, we noticed that one execution took 1 hour 20 mins to import 637 records as shown in the refresh history screenshot below. Thanks in advance for any inputs!


I suggest raising a support ticket so the stream can be inspected
